# PHP/Javascript/HTML - return false; doesn't work in link, my function doesn't start

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem with creating link, which shouldn't start "href" and instead of that it should run my javaScript function. Code:

**A LINK**

```
echo("<a href='sites/home_site.html' onClick='ChangeDIVContent(); return false;'>Just Test</a><br>");
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
  function ChangeDIVContent(){
    var using_content = "<?php echo $_SESSION['moving_text']; ?>";
    document.getElementById("content_div").innerHTML = using_content;
  }
</script>
```

Div is called "content_div" and $_SESSION['moving_text'] is set correctly.

**Problem** is, when I try short string (example: "ANYTHING"), it works.
When I use long string with spaces or empty rows, it doesn't and it runs "href" instead of my javascript function.

Any idea?

Comment: Aright. I missed that.

Comment: Should your comment help me somehow? Because it didn't. Never mind, I guess.

Comment: Use `<a href='#' ...>...</a>` then.  Why are you giving a path in href attribute

Comment: anu, I tried. Still same.... It runs "href" either.... Just without any URL inside.

Comment: You can use `preventDefault()` in your javascript function
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: What do you mean by "it runs href"? Try using `e.preventDefault()` in your function

Comment: encapsulate your javascript into a separate `<script></script>`  tag and create a new `function` for it, then do:  `<a href='javascript: myfunction()'>`

Comment: There must be an error in your code, causing the js to fail -> the link to submit. Could you post the code from browsers side ( what the php outputs)

Comment: Please update the code with the long string you are trying?

Comment: spaces are converted into  %20  URL encoding for <a href> tags so you cant have spaces on some browsers

Comment: @SuperUser, tried. Put into the function. Nothing happened.
anu, I mean, that "return false" doesn't work and href does.
mike510a, sorry, didn't get it. I hate it in "script" tags, nothing more.
Jonasw, I have no idea how. With "ob_flush" or smth?
Arjit, well, it's the same code. But longer string, nothing else.

Comment: @mike510a, so what am I supposed to do with that? I do have spaces in text of the file. "home_site.html" is full of .. text, nothing else. (spaces/empty rows).

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a> Can it be worked?

Comment: @JayminsFakeAccount, tried. Nothing. It must be something with length of the text. It works when it's short.

Comment: <a onclick="jsfunction()" href="javascript:void(0);"> this is the only basic syntax that should work!

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow like this and then see its work.
```

A LINK

```
<a title="<?php echo lang('Application_Query'); ?>"       onclick="showUrlInDialogIframe('<?php echo site_url('application/application_query/' . $application->application_id) ?>','Application Query');" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="fa fa-file"></span></a>
```

A Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUrlInDialogIframe(Urls,tl){
            if(tl){

            }else{
                var tl = 'Application View'
            }
            $("#ajxViewDgIframe").contents().find('body').html('');
            setTimeout(function(){
            $("#ajxViewDgIframeDV").dialog({
                    title: tl,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width:'80%',
                    closeText: "Close",
                    dialogClass: "no-close",
                    modal: true,
                    open: function(ev, ui){
                        $('#ajxViewDgIframe').attr('src',Urls);
                    },
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: "OK",
                            click: function() {
                                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }).dialog('open');
            }, 200);
            $("#ajxViewDgIframeDV").removeClass('displayNone');         
}

</script>
```